# What is the return type of address-of (&) operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```cpp
int main(){
    int i = 0;
    int *p = 123;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is: `invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] int *p = 123;`

I know `int *p = &i;` could make this work, but how the complier convert the `&i` type to `int *` type (what return type of & is)?

Thanks for anyone explaining this to me!

Comment: Because that, literally, is what the C++ standard says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access):

> For an expression of the form
>
> `& expr`
>
> If the operand is an lvalue expression of some object or function type T, operator& creates and returns a prvalue of type T*, with the same cv qualification, that is pointing to the object or function designated by the operand.

So, the type of the expression `&i` is an `int*`, where `i` is of type `int`.

---

Note that for expressions of this form where `expr` is of class type, the address-of operator may be overloaded, and there are no constraints on the type that can be returned from this overloaded operator.